# Java: replace substring using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of strings that need the first section up to the full stop replaced with a new string

e.g `anp_packlistepos.warenausgang` replaced with `anp_tracking_view.warenausgang`

I'm currently using Vaadin 14 and java version corretto 17

```
List<String> newconfigdto = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s : configdto) {
    newconfigdto.add(s.replace("\\S+(?=\\.)", "ANP_TRACKING_VIEW"));
}
```

After a bit of research I found that I was able to replace the string using this regex formel in regex101, but it does not work in my Java program.

Comment: take a look at the method call of .replace(). it does not accept a regex

Comment: `s.replaceAll("\\S+(?=\\.)", "ANP_TRACKING_VIEW")`

Answer (score 0):

Java's [String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) only does plaintext replacements.

If you want to use a regex pattern to replace characters, use either [String#replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) or [String#replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-).